# How to Check AsigneeId is User?

Tags: apex, permission-sets

Below is the code, I would like to get only user ID not the group id

```
 for(PermissionSetAssignments permSetAssignmentObj :  [SELECT AssigneeId from PermissionSetAssignments ])
 {
    // check AssigneeId  is user ID  and add to Set 
}
```

anything other than '005%' ?

Comment: so AssigneeId is returning groupId?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to only include `User` assignees in your query, you can use `Assignee.Type`:

```
SELECT AssigneeId FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE Assignee.Type = 'User'
```

See also: [Filtering on Polymorphic Relationship Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_filtering_polymorphic_relationships.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use:

```
if(permSetAssignmentObj.AssigneeId.getSObjectType() == User.getSObjectType())
{
    // do something
}
```

More info on the ID class [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_id.htm).